# Can this error message be improved?

Tags: feature-request, error-message

I am trying to edit an answer I gave. When I hit the Save Edits button it repeatedly says in a red box:

> An error occurred submitting the edit.

The question is on hold, so that could be the reason (but probably not, since I got the same error trying to edit this question).

Comment: Generally, that is a generic message indicating a client side failure, not a server-side failure.  Do you see any errors in your browser's console when you get this error?  Or do you have a flaky internet connection?

Comment: @psubsee2003 My internet was not speedy at that time but I was successfully using it on other sites. After seeing someone else saying they got that message and determined it was related to content, I stated shortening my answer. I was able to edit the question and add just the first paragraph of the new answer. Then I was able to edit it and add 3 lines of code. But when I tried to add the 3rd paragraph, or 3rd and 4th, it would give me the error. However, the next day I was able to successfully edit it. I will check the browser console window next time.